# How can i create and display a self designed window on current webpage instead of popup?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

I want to create and display a self designed window on current webpage instead of popup as you can see on this page
[Open the link and click first "Demo" button on that page.](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/#)

and the same type window appeared when I tried to put a link on this question on stackoverflow which accepted my link.

for example facebook also uses this type of window to display tagged images.
please help me.

Comment: Isn't that link with the example a library that lets you do what's in the example? or http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: yes that contains a library and i checked your link it can also help me but i want a simple solution not a library
so please tell me the basics of this type of dialog and simple sample code that will help me

Comment: if you cant then tell me how can I use your link's code in my asp.net application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the exact code to popup a div box then here it is. Displaying the div box in the centre of the browser is harder, and will involve some more javascript to work out the centre.

Note the 'return false;' in the OnClientClick event of the button. This stops the button performing a postback and reloading the entire page.

```
<head runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function togglePopUp(div_id) {
                var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
                if (el.style.display == 'block') { el.style.display = 'none'; }
                else { el.style.display = 'block'; }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnPopUp" OnClientClick="togglePopUp('popUpDiv'); return false;"
                 text="Pop Up a div boxt" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div id="popUpDiv" 
            style="
                display:none;
                position:absolute;
                top:100px;
                left:100px;
                background-color:Gray;
                z-index: 10002;">
             My popup box
             </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanx man your exact code helped me a lot and worked perfectly. If i will feel any difficulty i will comment here please reply for that. thanx again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET, that functionality is available in the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx).

It's also possible to do it using straight up HTML and JavaScript.

You simply create a div with the content that you want in the pop-up, and set its "Display" property to "none".

Upon user interaction (mouse click, button click, etc) use JavaScript to set the Display to "block".  (There is a bit more to it, but that's the gist of it.)

Of course, you can just get the component that does it from the page you linked to as well.

---

For another way to do it, and a fuller explanation, there's a full example with source code here:  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/modal-popup-window-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: thanks for helping but i don't know where to put that div inside my webpage source code, i tried this before by making a div with my contents on end of my webpage setting its position:fixed; in center but its not showing up